# Activemq network with different server versions

Tags: networking, activemq-classic, messagebroker

I have an activeMQ network with 2 instances. Those 2 instances are running 5.5 version of activeMQ. I want to add a new server in 5.9 version. Is this feasible? What should I have in mind? Any gotchas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't test the network of brokers between versions.  It may work but we encourage users to upgrade all their brokers to the latest release once the messages contained in those broker's stores have been migrated to a new broker.  You can do this by networking an older broker to a newer one and then creating a subscription on any destination that has messages on the old broker on the new one and letting the demand drain the old broker.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. Secondly, you suggest to turn all clients from the old broker to the new one? Or there is an internal procedure that drains the messages from the old broker to the new?

Comment: You can either turn the client to the new one or create a subscription on the new one via the web console.